# Node JS app hosting

Tags: node.js, hosting

I am relatively new to Node JS, I've built three small application I would like to host. Is there anyone who could provide a good starting point to learn how to deploy an app to one of the many services available? So far I am astonished by the lack of support from the companies who offer this service, as well as the vast amount of problems I am running into so if anyone has any tips, please help.

Comment: most cloud based services like https://www.heroku.com/ require you to deploy through git with a json file attached. I assume places like https://www.nodejitsu.com/ are the same. I recently built my own node server for running a few small apps. took me about half a day.

Comment: On heroku, you just push your git repository, and it's done. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#deploy-your-application-to-heroku
It is done in the same way (you just push your git/svn/hg repository to the server or just upload your app, which consists of code itself and a json file) on other cloud services. (i actually used that only on appfog and heroku, but fast googling shows that it is done the same way on other services)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This is](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Node-Hosting) cloud platforms compatible with node.js. The most popular heroku, nodejitsu, appfog (my choice).

Comment: Why is this your choice ?

Comment: If you are looking for the free trial solution for the fast deploy of your app, then I would advice you to use [EvenNode](https://www.evennode.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Heroku 
https://www.heroku.com/

It's super easy to use and provides easy integration of mongo db

Also If in future u create ionic app , u can host them too

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying several of those options, and on my opinion Nodejitsu is by far the best, the thing is that is not free (just the first month). So, because of that you may wanna try Heroku (it didnt like me). Another option in beta is Cloudno.de.